# Selecting columns in DataLoadOptions

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm using the DataLoadOptions to retrieve the User that modified a Customer's details,

```
DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<Customer>(c => c.ModifiedBy);
```

However, I only want the User's ID and FirstName and not all the columns.  Is there a way to specify the columns you want in the DataLoadOptions?

Tables:

```
Customer (ID, FirstName, LastName, Email, ModifiedByUserID etc)
User (ID, FirstName, LastName, etc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any way of specifying the columns to load with [`DataLoadOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.aspx).

There is an [`DataLoadOptions.AssociateWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.associatewith.aspx) Method that allows you to limit the amount of data retrieved but this is in terms of records.

If this where possible, the system had to somehow know that a record was only loaded with a specified number of columns. When the not-loaded columns where requested in the future, Linq would have to fetch only these columns from the database. I don't think that Linq is capable of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify it programatically the way you phrased it, but you certainly can do it - if your goal is to minimize columns returned.

**DataLoadOptions**

```
options.LoadWith<OrderInfo>(OrderInfo => OrderInfo.SourceSystemOrderDetails);
options.LoadWith<OrderInfo>(OrderInfo => OrderInfo.Packages);
```

**Query**

```
var orders = context.OrderInfo.Select(x => new
                {

                    ID = x.SourceSystemOrderDetails.OrderId,
                    Name = x.SourceSystemOrderDetails.Name,
                    PackageCount = x.Packages.Count()

                }).ToArray();
```

This will give you an anonymous object. In the database it will only return the columns specified. You can also just create your business object here if you want.